# Spring mvc form not reading some character sequence

Tags: spring-mvc, utf-8, special-characters

I have implemented a basic spring mvc form. Now, it is able to read special characters like     @#$%^&* but there are few things which is missing like, if I type "..........", it reads it as something like "?.." or it is not reading text between < and > characters. I googled out to find out the solution and so it seems that spring mvc by default do not follow UTF-8 pattern. So, I appended the following code in web.xml

```
           <filter>
   <filter-name>springCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
 <param-name>encoding</param-name>
 <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  </filter>
```

I am using

```
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

in my page. Also, in my server.xml I am using

```
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

But the problem is still there. Can anyone suggest me what I am missing out or there is any other cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution finally...You need to use

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Instead of

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

In your jsp files.